# How to generate fake password with javascript using casual library

Tags: javascript, npm, protractor

I need to generate a password with:

- min length : 7
- max length : 15
- Uppercase : one letter at least
- Lowercase : one letter at least
- special character `~ ! @ # $ % ^ * ( ) _ +` ?

I used casual lib, but i'm unable to generate special character. Could any one help me on this issue?

```
var casual = require('casual');
var password = casual.password.substring(10,{

    length: 10,
    uppercase: true,
    lowercase: true,
    number: true,
    symbols: true,
    strict: true
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be fairly easy to roll your own:

```
const lowercaseLetter = () => casual.random_element('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split(''));
const uppercaseLetter = () => casual.random_element('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split(''));
const specialCharacter = () => casual.random_element('~!@#$%^*()_+'.split(''));
const anyCharacter = () => casual.random_element([lowercaseLetter(), uppercaseLetter(), specialCharacter()]);

casual.define('specialPassword', function() {
    const length = casual.integer(from = 7, to = 15);
    const pw = [lowercaseLetter(), uppercaseLetter(), specialCharacter()];
    while (pw.length < length) {
       pw.push(anyCharacter());
    } 
    return pw.join('');
});
```

You should, of course, shuffle `pw` on the last line if you care for "safer" passwords.